# Problem setting up Thunderbird on 14.04.1 install

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, imap

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 and am trying to set up Thunderbird (31.0).

I follow the usual setup (I have done this many times in the last few months on 12.04 and on another machine with 14.04) and use an existing email address, it finds the correct ports/connection security and then the status line says "Mail for : Sending login information...". If I click on Inbox it just hangs indefinitely.

(My other machines use Thunderbird to access my imap account with no issues.)

There is no firewall issue. Tcpdump on the server & client machines shows traffic on imap/imap2. In fact the traffic just keeps on going & going & going until I kill Thunderbird.

Any suggestions appreciated. I am stuck with SquirrelMail on my machine for the moment!

**Update**:

I downloaded an older version from
http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/24.7.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/
and bunzip2 & untarred the file, then ran ./thunderbird/thunderbird. This worked as expected (but is not integrated into the standard Ubuntu window manager setup).

In addition, I removed my .thunderbird directory and was able to create a new account without any issues.

If I start the 31.0 Thunderbird it just shows the busy icon with the status message "Looking for folders".

**More info**:

When trying to connect using either Thunderbird 31.0 or 24.7 this morning I got the 'too many connections' every time, so was unable to check mail. After some slog, I discovered that the imap server had many messages of the form:

```
Jul 28 10:35:10 crow xinetd[2126]: FAIL: imap per_source_limit from=::ffff:192.168.0.8
```

Restarting xinetd fixed the problem. However, since this is the first time I have ever encountered this limit with xinetd, I suspect it may be related to the problems at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by OP:

In my home directory I have some links to fairly deep directories. I use the "IMAP Server Directory" option to point to my actual mail. While I haven't confirmed this with tcpdump, when I remove the links, the 31.0 Thunderbird seems to work as expected. When I restore the links, it just hangs as before. So I am guessing that 31.0 Thunderbird doesn't restrict the directory search to the "IMAP Server Directory".

Not ideal, but I can live with the workaround.

Comment: That's okay, you can always post your own answer remember - please don't edit your question to answer it!

Comment: I wasn't sure what the policy was here and didn't have the energy to search meta right now!

Comment: Yeah have a look at http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with the StackExchange setup, mainly http://math.stackexchange.com, but answers to maths. questions are typically cut & dried, here I didn't actually get an answer, but found an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Yes, I saw 55k+ is impressive! I have a passion for maths but I'm not good enough to be involved in the site... Often on AU we don't get an answer, but if it solves it, we like it posted as it may help others in the future!

Comment: Thanks Tim - hopefully it helps someone, albeit I hope no one has the abysmally complex home setup that I have!